# Updating angular.js service object without extend/copy possible?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have 2 services and would like to update a variable in the 1st service from the 2nd service.
In a controller, I am setting a scope variable to the getter of the 1st service.

The problem is, the view attached to the controller doesn't update when the service variable changes UNLESS I use angular.extend/copy. It seems like I should just be able to set `selectedBuilding` below without having to use extend/copy. Am I doing something wrong, or is this how you have to do it?

**controller**

```
app.controller('SelectedBuildingCtrl', function($scope, BuildingsService) {
    $scope.building = BuildingsService.getSelectedBuilding();    
});
```

**service 1**

```
app.factory('BuildingsService', function() {
    var buildingsList = [];
    var selectedBuilding = {};
    // buildingsList populated up here
    ...
    var setSelectedBuilding = function(buildingId) {
        angular.extend(selectedBuilding, _.find(
            buildingsList, {'building_id': buildingId})
        );
    };
    var getSelectedBuilding = function() {
        return selectedBuilding;
    };
    ...
    return {
        setSelectedBuilding: setSelectedBuilding,
        getSelectedBuilding: getSelectedBuilding    
    }
});
```

**service 2**

```
app.factory('AnotherService', function(BuildingsService) {
    ...
    // something happens, gives me a building id
    BuildingsService.setSelectedBuilding(building_id);
    ...
});
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not sure if this could work for you better, but you may want to look into Angular events. See: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope. In particular `$broadcast`, `$emit`, and `$on` may be of interest to you. For example, when the selected building changes you could broadcast an event (e.g. `selectedBuildingChanged`), which could be `$on`'d in your controller to react accordingly.

Comment: @brianmarco I started out using `$broadcast` and `$on` but it ended up  being much harder to test than getters/setters. The rest of the team is just getting up to speed with angular so I'm trying to make things as explicit as possible.

Comment: Ah ok. Any chance you can share your difficulties with the testing? We use events for some things with our app but to be honest we probably don't do very in depth testing for them.

Comment: Sure, when unit testing the `$broadcast` events I ended up having to use jasmine's `spyOn($rootScope, 'broadcast').andCallThrough()`. 

But since $rootScope was calling other events from 3rd party plugins testing this involved 1. a lot of mocking or 2. being really clever with calling `$rootScope.$apply()` throughout the tests to make sure I could discard the events I didn't care about and catch the ones I did. I decided it was getting too complex and looked for a way to use `$broadcast` less.

Comment: Ahhh I see.  Tx very much for sharing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you execute this code:

```
$scope.building = BuildingsService.getSelectedBuilding();
```

`$scope.building` is **copied** a reference to **the same object in memory** as your service's `selectedBuilding`. When you assign another object to `selectedBuilding`, the `$scope.building` still references to the **old object**. That's why the view is not updated and you have to use `angular.copy/extend`.

You could try the following solution to avoid this problem if you need to assign new objects to your `selectedBuilding`:

```
app.factory('BuildingsService', function() {
        var buildingsList = [];
        var building = { //create another object to **hang** the reference
            selectedBuilding : {}
         }
        // buildingsList populated up here
        ...
        var setSelectedBuilding = function(buildingId) {
            //just assign a new object to building.selectedBuilding 
        };
        var getSelectedBuilding = function() {
            return building; //return the building instead of selectedBuilding 
        };
        ...
        return {
            setSelectedBuilding: setSelectedBuilding,
            getSelectedBuilding: getSelectedBuilding    
        }
    });
```

With this solution, you have to update your views to replace `$scope.building` bindings to `$scope.building.selectedBuilding`.

In my opinion, I will stick to `angular.copy/extend` to avoid this unnecessary complexity.

Answer (score 1):

I dont believe you need an extend in your service. You should be able to watch the service directly and respond to the changes:

```
app.controller('SelectedBuildingCtrl', function($scope, BuildingsService) {
  // first function is evaluated on every $digest cycle
  $scope.$watch(function(scope){
    return BuildingsService.getSelectedBuilding();
  // second function is a callback that provides the changes
  }, function(newVal, oldVal, scope) {
    scope.building = newVal;
  }
});
```

More on $watch: [https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.16/docs/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope](https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.16/docs/api/ng/type/%24rootScope.Scope)